# How to use Max in the where clause

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I need to count latest date records (REPORT_DATE column).

It will be very helpful if I get this in the where clause

```
Select count(*) FROM DATA_EXPORT WHERE
REPORT_DATE = MAX(REPORT_DATE)
```

ORA-00934: group function is not allowed here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this one :

```
Select count(*) 
  FROM DATA_EXPORT 
 WHERE REPORT_DATE = (select MAX(REPORT_DATE) from  DATA_EXPORT)
   AND STATUS = 'Open'
```